# Google Drive API: Can't upload certain filetypes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I created a form and a simple server with google appengine with which to upload arbitrary file types to my google drive. The form fails to work for certain file types and just gives this error instead:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v1/files?alt=json returned "Unsupported content with type: application/pdf">
```

Aren't pdf files supported?

The appengine code that does the upload goes somewhat like this:

```
def upload_to_drive(self, filestruct):
    resource = {
        'title': filestruct.filename,
        'mimeType': filestruct.type,
    }
    resource = self.service.files().insert(
    body=resource,
    media_body=MediaInMemoryUpload(filestruct.value,
                                     filestruct.type),
    ).execute()


def post(self):
      creds = StorageByKeyName(Credentials, my_user_id, 'credentials').get()
      self.service = CreateService('drive', 'v1', creds)
      post_dict = self.request.POST
      for key in post_dict.keys():
          if isinstance(post_dict[key], FieldStorage):#might need to import from cgi
             #upload to drive and return link
             self.upload_to_drive(post_dict[key]) #TODO: there should be error handling here
```

I've successfully used it for MS Office documents and images. It doesn't work for textfiles too and gives this error:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v1/files?alt=json returned "Multipart content has too many non-media parts">
```

I've tried unsetting the 'mimeType' value in the resource dict to let google drive set it automatically. I also tried unsetting the mime type value in the MediaInMemoryUpload constructor. Sadly, none of both worked.

Comment: Could you try with the resumable upload protocol? You can easily switch to resumable upload by specifying `resumable=True` to the `MediaInMemoryUpload` initializer: `media_body=MediaInMemoryUpload(filestruct.value, filestruct.type, resumable=True)`.

Comment: I had tried `resumable = True`, that didn't work. Sorry, I forgot to state that I tried that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using an old version of the Python client library and referring to Drive API v1, while Drive API v2 has been available since the end of June.

Please try updating your library and check the complete Python sample at https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like charm! It turns out that I was using an outdated version of the Python client library that I copied off the DrEdit example weeks ago.

Comment: It looks like that link goes to a 404. Do you have a comparable link?